# Bootstrap Datatable sorting default

Tags: datatable

I want sorting default column.
If I sort other column and refresh or reload the page it should sort the default column.

```
order: [[ 7, "desc" ]]
```

Comment: can you show your full datatable configure code here.so that i can help you out.

Comment: That seems correct, mind you that columns count zero based, so in this case there should be at least 8 columns.